# Explanation for the command "kill -n 9 0"

Tags: linux, bash, kill

I am searching `kill` command's full manual, but in `man kill` or even with Google, I cannot find this command's meaning below:

```
kill -n 9 0
```

I am sure it has a very easy answer.

Comment: You'll get a description of this from `kill --help`.

Comment: @GeorgeVasiliou: I don't think the linked duplicate is applicable as this question appears to be asking specifically about the `-n` option and it's lack of documentation.

Comment: @Jesse_b What i understand is that OP is looking information about the whole command not just `-n` switch.

Comment: @GeorgeVasiliou: OP said they were unable to find the information in the manual.  Everything about this command is in the manual except for the `-n`.  Either way the linked duplicate doesn't explain `-n` so it doesn't answer the question entirely.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> -n sig    SIG is a signal number

> Some of the more commonly used signals:
>
> ```
> 1       HUP (hang up)
> 2       INT (interrupt)
> 3       QUIT (quit)
> 6       ABRT (abort)
> 9       KILL (non-catchable, non-ignorable kill)
> 14      ALRM (alarm clock)
> 15      TERM (software termination signal)
> ```

```
kill: kill [-s sigspec | -n signum | -sigspec] pid | jobspec ... or kill -l [sigspec]
```

So your command is sending the `KILL` signal to the processes identified by 0.

The zero has a special meaning when used as the PID with `kill`. It means "Send the signal to all processes whose group ID is equal to the process group ID of the sender, and for which the process has permission." (that's from [a BSD manual](https://man.openbsd.org/kill) for the `kill` utility).  Or, [as POSIX puts](https://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/utilities/kill.html) it "If process number 0 is specified, all processes in the current process group shall be signaled".

---

The `-n` is optional you could also do:

```
kill -9 0
```

or

```
kill -KILL 0
```

Comment: I've gone through and deleted the old comment string since I believe everyone has made their points to each other. If you see a shortcoming of an answer, consider editing it to improve it. Short of that, comments should be aimed *directly* at improving the answer.  Being indirect doesn't help improve the answer. Comments are second-class citizens and should be deleted once the post has been improved by them.